# How Can I create object of Interface in PowerBuilder

Tags: .net, powerbuilder

I am using VcCom Api for communication between .Net and PowerBuilder application.
For this purpose I am Using VcCom Library in .Net and Powerbuilder projects. It works fine in .Net but when I add library file in Powerbuilder project and tries to create object of Interface(VcComSession) it gives me error.
Following is code snippest that i am using for ceating interfac object

```
VcComSession obj=create VcComSession;
cb_1.Text=obj.id;
obj.SendToAll("Message");
```

Kindly anybody help me to achive this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to declare a variable of type oleobject, then instantiate it and use its methods.

```
oleobject lobj // declaration
long ll_return
ll_return = lobj.connecttonewobject('<workspace.classname>')
IF ll_return < 0 THEN // errors, check for values in PB help
ELSE
   cb_1.text = lobj.id
   lobj.sendtoall("Message")
END IF
lobj.disconnectobject() // should always disconnect from COM objects
```